# CSS :nth-child() selector in a PHP constructed site

Tags: php, html, css

I have three CSS rules that define alternating styles, repeating every three items:

```
.container:nth-child(3n):after {
    /* Styleset 1 */
}

.container:nth-child(3n-1):after {
    /* Styleset 2 */
}

.container:nth-child(3n-2):after {
    /* Styleset 3 */
}
```

These work flawlessly in simple static HTML pages.

However, once applied to a website that writes multiple `div.container`s using a PHP `foreach` loop, the styles no longer alternate. Apparently only the `nth-child(3n-2)` style is now being applied to *all* `.container`s. The PHP looks like this:

```
<?php foreach ($articles as $article) { ?>
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Content creation -->
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

How does this happen?

Comment: Most likely your dynamically output HTML is different in structure – so go compare to that of the static, working version. Simply checking it for errors in the [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/) would be the next sensible step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If n is the first child, (3n-2) would compute to (3-2 = 1); apparently, every last one of those divs is now the first (and therefore only) child of its parent. I can't tell you exactly what to fix without seeing the rest of your code (is this loop inside of another loop which is creating a parent for each one?), but you probably have to move that loop up a level or otherwise ensure that all of your .containers are being created as siblings, and not as lonely, single children.

For future help with debugging nth-child issues, this is handy: http://css-tricks.com/examples/nth-child-tester/

Comment: They actually are not siblings anymore, a new title element is now inserted in front of all container elements. Is there no way to target them in correct order regardless of being siblings? I'm guessing that `nth-of-type()` would be an option, i'll try it out and report back.

Comment: `nth-of-type()` works a lot like `nth-child()` -- think of it as "nth-child-of-type". It would do the trick if they were all still siblings but were no longer the only children of their parent. Maybe try your nth-childs on whatever parent is being generated? I'm not sure why title elements are being generated at all -- they should only appear once per document, in the `<head>`.

Comment: Im sorry, i was not referring to actual `<title>` elements. My current DOM now looks like this: I have a wrapping `div#content`, and in this element there are two alternating divs, the one that i want to target and a different one. But im guessing that i'll have to just wrap each pair into a containing div, and everything's back to normal.